# SBS backup to linux share

Tags: centos, samba, windows-sbs-2011

Im currently looking for a solution regarding backing up windows to a network share which is located on a linux machine (Shared trough samba).

I cant get it to work with the current setup (SBS backup --> junction point to mapped driver --> mapped driver = samba share)

It keeps prompting for passwords and it has authentication issues, so now i am looking for other solutions which are completly automated. Are there any suggestions appart from samba to

Answer (score 0):

I recommend working through the Samba issues and you should have a fairly stable backup plan.

Another option would be to present the share via NFS and then install "Client Services for NFS" on your SBS machine.

Either way, you're stuck looking at Samba or NFS as a share from a Linux machine, unless you feel like staging the backup on the Windows machine before siphoning it off with `ssh` or `socat` under Cygwin *shudders*.